# jQuery loop on open dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I'm trying to display a minor animation to user that it is being submitted.

```
$("#textscreen").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).everyTime("1s", function(i) {
            var dots = '';
            if((i % 4) == 0)
            {
                dots = '';
            }
            else
            {
                dots = dots + ".";
            }

            $(this).html("<b>"+processText+dots+"</b>");
        }, 30);
    }
});
```

That is basically triggered when user clicks the submit button and it is triggered by calling like this:

```
DisplayModal("Submitting");
```

Since the button tries to POST on click, I've put in return false:

```
function button_OnClick()
{
    DisplayModal("Submitting");
    return false;
}
```

When I click on the button, the modal flashes up and disapears, then POSTs.

Why is the function being posted when I am returning false?

Comment: in the submit button you have to put onclick="return button_OnClick()";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) + I recommend you to put the call for 'DisplayModal' in try catch

Comment: It wasn't to do with preventDefault() as return false should have done the job. But trying Try..Catch, I was able to find that there was an error within the DisplayModal code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use preventDefault() function.